# Regex, get what's after the second occurence of a string

Tags: regex, string, find

I have a string of the following format:

`TEXT####TEXT####SPECIALTEXT`

I need to get the `SPECIALTEXT`, basically what is after the second occurrence of the `####`. I can't get it done. Thanks

Comment: You also said you "can't get it done", what have you tried?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The regex `(?:.*?####){2}(.*)` contains what you're looking for in its first group.

Comment: Like a charm! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using shell and can use `awk` for it:

From a file:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="####"} {print $3}' input_file
```

From a variable:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="####"} {print $3}' <<< "$input_variable"
```